# Screen command for buffer

Tags: gnu-screen

I want to read the contents of the file into the paste buffer and stdout it to the screen.
I did this:

```
screen -X readbuf /home/nitro/file|screen -X writebuf|cat /tmp/screen-exchange
```

but the `cat` command showed me the screen-exchange file with the previous result of the readbuf command. If I do these commands separately, everything will be correct and I'll get the modified screen-exchange file.

How can I perform all three commands readbuf, writebuf and cat at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those commands:

```
screen -X readbuf /home/nitro/file
screen -X writebuf
cat /tmp/screen-exchange
```

do not act as parts of a pipe, but your composite command attempts to treat them that way. That is, each step does not read the previous step's standard output, so there is less causal relationship among them than if you had typed

```
screen -X readbuf /home/nitro/file; screen -X writebuf; cat /tmp/screen-exchange
```

or

```
screen -X readbuf /home/nitro/file && screen -X writebuf && cat /tmp/screen-exchange
```